# Multi-line form submit button in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Is there a way for me to get the

```
<%= f.submit "Save Draft", :class => "button" %>
```

Button text onto two lines?

I'd like it to say

Save Draft -> big text

and finish later -> this line smaller sized

Comment: I guess it's a css matter (tag added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
You can not apply two different font sizes to the same button, you could however supply a mouse hover event for the form class that represents the button in css to change the colour or you could use jQuery to hange the text and colour

```
.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background: #eef;
}
```

Not sure what the jQuery code would look like though but more info can be found here on the mouseover event

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/